# GotoBLAS2 performance

Tags: c++, performance, fortran, lapack

I've got some code which performs a packed symmetric matrix inversion and multiplication using the LAPACK routines `DPPTRF`, `DPPTRI`, and `DSPMV`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640351/lapack-on-win32) is an older topic in which you can see the C++ code I use to invoke the LAPACK routines.

My code currently assembles a symmetric matrix which is mostly populated along the diagonal.

I am testing different BLAS and LAPACK implementations and I am comparing GotoBLAS2 with the reference LAPACK implementation from netlib.

Here is how I compile the netlib LAPACK code. I select the `.f` code files from source, and compile them all into a compact static library like this:

```
$ ls
ddot.f   dpptrf.f  dscal.f  dspr.f   dtpsv.f   lsame.f
dgemm.f  dpptri.f  dspmv.f  dtpmv.f  dtptri.f  xerbla.f
$ gfortran -c *.f
$ ar rcs liblapack_lite.a *.o
```

I can then link this lib to my C++ application using `-llapack_lite -lgfortran`.

I then tried using GotoBLAS2. I got it from [here](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/gotoblas2). The package contained scripts that compiled a massive 19MB static lib automatically. It works great with my existing code by linking it: `-lgoto2_nehalemp-r1.13`.

I felt that this went well at first. With GotoBLAS2, on large problem sets (inverting 1000x1000 or larger matrices) I saw about a 6x performance increase. Since GotoBLAS is threaded for my architecture and reference LAPACK is single threaded I thought this was reasonable. System monitor also showed >300% CPU usage to corroborate.

Here's where it gets weird. I think, what if I optimize the reference implementation?

I recompile my lapack_lite lib like this: `gfortran -c -O3 *.f`

My lapack_lite lib now outperforms GotoBLAS2 even on a 3200x3200 matrix inversion, *using only one thread*. It also consumes ~80MB less RAM.

The subsequent packed matrix-vector multiply does happen faster with GotoBLAS, however.

How is this even remotely possible? Did the make configuration of the GotoBLAS package fail to use an optimization switch with gfortran?

Comment: Well have you checked the GotoBLAS2 build scripts? Presumably you built from source, so it shouldn't be too hard to see how the compiler is being invoked...

Comment: do you have lots of zeros in your matrix?  reference blas may screen out zeros essentially removing much of ops.

Comment: Does the reference version get the right answer?  I ask this because the flags are mostly set at -O2 for very specific reasons.

Comment: I am pretty sure it produces the right answer, at least for the problems I've been solving. I'll keep that in mind and compile with -O2 the next time. To address the "screening zeros"... Why would an optimized implementation like gotoblas not do something like this to help performance? ... Ultimately, though, I am never ever going to actually calculate the full matrix inverse. I have 3 solver stages which tackle the same system: Full dense matrix, banded matrix after permuting using reverse cuthill mckee, and CHOLMOD. The full matrix method does not scale well at all.

Comment: Only compare between parallel and serial for the same library, how would you hope to know the reason of the performance differences?  If you compile lapack without optimization options, that's no good, use `-O2` since gfortran by default will not optimize your code.  Then check how GotoBLAS is compiled and check performance running a single thread as well.